# increasing sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

suppose $A_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$. Also if $A_{k} \subseteq A_{k+1} $, does it follow that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \mathbb{R} $?. I know this is obvious but I dont know how to show the other inclusion: that is $ \mathbb{R}$ lives inside the bigcup

Comment: $\cup [0, 1-1/n] = [0,1)$

Comment: Note that since $\{A_k\}$ is increasing, so $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\lim_{k\to\infty}A_k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is that obvious?  It's not even true, which is why you're unable to show it.

Examples of countable unions of subsets of $\mathbb R$, which are not $\mathbb R$:

- $A_k=\{0\}$ for all $k$.  Then $A_k\subseteq A_{k+1}$ for all $k$, but $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\{0\}$.
- Even if you require that the sequence be strictly increasing, consider $A_k=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$.  Then $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\mathbb N$.
- If we require that each of the $A_k$ be an interval, we can have $A_k=[0,1-1/k]$ (as in Prahlad's comment) - then $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=[0,1)$.

Perhaps you could give some reasons why you think this is obvious.  Then we can help you see where your mistake is.